# rostest file layout- can't find/tries to compile/no rule to make target, existing .test file

Tags: rostest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I compile my test bench using rosbuild_add_gtest then roscore is normally not running, and the test fails to connect. Which is why I'm trying to setup an rostest file.

I have written a differential_drive.test file in differential_drive/smurf/ ie. differential_drive/smurf/differential_drive.test

FYI smurf directory name used to differentiate values, only for testing/debugging.

Just FYI ls output from differential_drive dir:

```
$ ls
bin  build  CMakeLists.txt  launch  lib  mainpage.dox  Makefile  manifest.xml  msg  msg_gen  smurf  src  test
```

I can successfully run this test using:

```
$ rostest smurf/differential_drive.test
... logging to /home/tobor/.ros/log/rostest-meltybrain-17188.log
[ROSUNIT] Outputting test results to /home/tobor/.ros/test_results/differential_drive/rostest-smurf_differential_drive.xml
testdifferential_drive_ros_tests ... ok

[ROSTEST]-----------------------------------------------------------------------

...

SUMMARY
 * RESULT: SUCCESS
 * TESTS: 6
 * ERRORS: 0
 * FAILURES: 0

rostest log file is in /home/tobor/.ros/log/rostest-meltybrain-17188.log
```

However I am having trouble setting up the CMakeLists.txt file to run this automatically.

Here are the relevent CMakeLists.txt lines:

```
rosbuild_add_executable(
  test_2/differential_drive_ros_tests
  TestRunner.cpp
...
)
rosbuild_add_gtest_build_flags(test_2/differential_drive_ros_tests)
rosbuild_add_rostest(smurf/differential_drive.test)
```

Some make test output:

```
[100%] Built target test_2/differential_drive_ros_tests
[100%] Built target tests
make[3]: *** No rule to make target '../test/smurf/differential_drive.test', needed by 'test/CMakeFiles/rostest_smurf_differential_drive.test'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** [test/CMakeFiles/rostest_smurf_differential_drive.test.dir/all] Error 2
```

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53762/rostest-file-layout--can%27t-find/tries-to-compile/no-rule-to-make-target,-existing-.test-file/) by [toborguru](https://answers.ros.org/users/4090/toborguru/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK so the CMakelists.txt file was in the test directory. Basically everything got confused as to where the test file was during the build.

Solution, explicitly state where the file is in the project:

```
rosbuild_add_rostest(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/test/differential_drive.test)
```

or, per my example:

```
rosbuild_add_rostest(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/smurf/differential_drive.test)
```

---

Originally posted by [toborguru](https://answers.ros.org/users/4090/toborguru/) with karma: 16 on 2013-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0